# What would be the best approch to build following and followers system in mongodb (No-SQL)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I want to build a system of following and followers in which people can send and receive the request in my app.
I just have a brief idea that I have to make followers and the following array in users collection, Is there any other approach which I can use in my app database using MongoDB and manage network efficiently.